# Send file upload to another page

Tags: php

I got `$_File['file']` by PHP. Now, I want send to another page by url. How do I send it?

ex: page `upload_first.php` => `$file = $_File['file']`

Location: `www.example.com/upload_second.php?file=$file`

--Thanks

Comment: No you cant, at least not by this way !!!, you cant send file using querystring , only text values

Comment: You can upload the file in upload_first.php and save it in the server and pass the file location from upload_first.php to upload_second.php

Answer (score 0):

If upload_second.php expects to read the file from $_FILES array (or if you don't control it), you have to perform another HTTP POST request, resending the file. curl may help here

If it expects path to the file on the system, you first need to save the file (using move_uploaded_file function) as it will disappear as soon as your script end, then redirect the user to the new page.

The last alternative, if upload_second.php just contains some code to manipulate the file, to `include` it without actually redirecting the user.

Answer (score 0):

To parse a file to an other file you need something like this: `$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];` and `$file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];`